# How to get Datatable components rerendered upon state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react-redux application this has the following code structure, which is running correctly.

```
class Customers extends Component{
  state = {
    showAddCustomerForm : false
  }
  toggleAddCustomerForm = ()=>{
    this.setState({showAddCustomerForm: !this.state.showAddCustomerForm})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Fragment>
<AddCustomerForm />
                    <Datatable
                      options={{
                        data: this.props.customers,
                        buttons: [
                          {
                            extend: 'csv',
                            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>Excel'
                          },
                          {
                            text: 'Add Customer',
                            action: this.toggleAddCustomerForm
                          }
                        ],
                        columns: [
                          { data: "name" },
                          { data: "email" },
                          { data: "mobile", "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>" },
                          { data: "landline", "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"}
                        ]
                      }}
                      filter="true"
                      className="table table-striped table-bordered"
                      width="100%"
                    />
      </Fragment>
)
}
}
```

The Datatable Component uses the redux store for rendering the table. When I add a new Customer using the AddCustomerForm I update Redux store. This actually changes the application state, So I expect the Datatable Component to RE-Render and show me the new customer in the table. however, this does not happen. If I hit  it shows me correctly.

I understand that both React and jQuery Datatables manage DOM independently, but I am sure there must be a way to use datatables in a rerenderable component...

Please help..

Comment: If this.props.customers was updated then it should automatically re render. Can you share your code which connects to store and dispatch add customer action?

Comment: the this.props.customers gets the correct data and it renders initially. however, the jquery component inside that datatable does not re-render upon state change. The datatable component is a blackbox for me. I just send data: this.props.customers and it renders the table with data. the challenge is getting it to re-render

Comment: Can you console.log the.props.customers when you added new customer??? Does that update too when adding new value?

Comment: Yesss! the new records gets entered in the database and also in the store.. I can see the data in redux store as well... As I said before, if I press F5 the records is shown in the datatable. but is does not refresh automatically.

Comment: Actually I need to somehow get the datatable object dropped and rebuild automatically... I presume.

Comment: I think you have updated database when adding the customers but you have never updated the store. Please check the diff for adding customer action.

Answer (score 1):

For datatables fed by HTML or JavaScript source, I'm afraid, there's no way to re-render datatable upon source data modification.

However, it is rather good news from the standpoint of data consistency across multiple clients who might use your application simultaneously. To maintain that, you may use AJAX requests to update back-end data which all the users refer to and, upon successful update, throw [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) to sync your client with backend.

If, for some reason, you might wish to update your datatable locally, you may consider cleaning table contents and re-populating it with your data, like that:

```
//datatable initialization
var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        data: myDataArray
    });
//source data modification
myDataArray.push({
    attr1: "value",
    attr2: "value"...
});
//purge datatable contents
datatable.clear();
//re-populate datatable
$.each(myDataArray, function () {
    datatable.row().add(this);
});
//re-render up to date datatable
datatable.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I am unsure about the development platform you are relating to... I need to use datatables on React platform. I have already written the following in the shouldComponentUpdate() but it does not get triggered.   shouldComponentUpdate() {
    const element = $(this.refs.table);
    element.DataTable().clear();
    element.DataTable().rows.add(this.props.options.data)
    element.DataTable().draw();
    // return false;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can update datatable by implementing the "componentDidUpdate" function of your component. Example:

```
componentDidUpdate=()=>{
    //console.log("Component did update");
    if (this.props.customers.length>0){
          this.createTable()
          this.updateTable();
    }


};
```

Then implement the function for updating data. E.g

```
updateTable=()=>{
    let table=$('#mytable').DataTable();

    table.clear();
    table.rows.add(this.props.consumers).draw();
```

}

I would also create the table using javascript rather than in the JSX. That way you can destroy the table and create it afresh every time you want to update

```
createTable=()=>{

  if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#mytable' ) ) {
    $('#mytable').DataTable().destroy();
  }

 let table=$('#mytable').DataTable({

      "columns":columns,

  });
```

And the JSX would only contain the id of the table

```
<table id="mytable">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will try it soon and respond... In fact I tried something similar a while ago.... I will try your answer now.